# Assignment of function pointers (effective c++ item 35)

Tags: c++, function-pointers, effective-c++

In *effective c++, item 35*, the author introduces the strategy pattern via function pointers. Specifically on page 172

```
class GameCharacter; 
int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc);
class GameCharacter {
public:
  typedef int (*HealthCalcFunc)(const GameCharacter&);
  explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)//why not &defaultHealthCalc?
  : healthFunc(hcf)
  {}
  int healthValue() const
  { return healthFunc(*this); }
  ...
private:
  HealthCalcFunc healthFunc;
};
```

On the sixth line, why the assignment to the function pointer `HealthCalcFunc` is `defaultHealthCalc` instead of `&defaultHealthCalc` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the compiler knows that you are assigning a value to a pointer-to-function, it is enough to specify the name of the function you want -- the syntax is unambiguous.

If you wanted to add the ampersand to make it clear, the syntax allows that, but it isn't necessary.

Similarly, when calling a function from a pointer, you can either use the name of the pointer directly (as is done in the example code), or explicitly dereference it using the '*' operator. The compiler knows what you mean in either case.

Comment: [You can dereference the function pointer as much as you want :P](https://godbolt.org/g/X4Qhvd)